# How to get multiple parameters from boost::split

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

How can split a std::string so that both the values of structure object get filled.

```
q.Qcmd = "Command1"
q.timeValue = 1.0
```

This is the sample code.

```
struct QueueCommand
{
 std::vector<std::string>QCmd;
 std::vector<float>timeValue;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 std::string str = "command1|1.0"
 std::string str1 = "command2|2.0"
 QueueCommand q;
 boost::split( q,str,boost::is_any_of("|"));  // need to fill Qcmd and timevalue
 boost::split( q,str1,boost::is_any_of("|"));
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not a correct usage of `boost::split` because the first parameter has to be a container for `string`, and `split` does not know how to fill the specific structure. I give you hints on how to solve it. I have not tested the code, but you can try yourself:

First, you have to declare a vector to store the parts:

```
std::vector<std::string> parts;
```

Then, `boost::split` can split the command string:

```
boost::split( parts, str, boost::is_any_of("|"));
```

Reserve enough space in the corresponding `QueueCommand` variable:

```
q.QCmd.resize(parts.size() - 1);
```

(the last one contains the float number). Copy the strings to the structure. You have to make sure the parts array contains at least two elements:

```
std::copy(parts.begin(), parts.begin() + parts.size() - 1, q.QCmd.begin());
```

Set the float part of the struct:

```
q.timeValue = boost::lexical_cast<float>(parts[parts.size() - 1]);
```

**5gon12eder suggestion in comments**:

Which seems more elegant and efficient, but requires C++11 for `std::move`:

```
q.timeValue = boost::lexical_cast<float>(parts.back());
parts.pop_back();
q.QCmd = std::move(parts);
```

Comment: I'd *first* do `q.timeValue = boost::lexical_cast<float>(parts.back());`, then a `parts.pop_back();` and then `q.QCmd = std::move(parts)`.  Seems both simpler and more efficient.  If you want to squeeze the last byte out, do a `shrink_to_fit()` after the `pop_back()`.  (I assume your `reserve()` was meant to be a `resize()`, otherwise the size of the vector will probably be wrong / the behavior undefined.)

Comment: Ahh you're right. Very nice suggestion. I'm changing the `reserve`, but I'll leave your code if you want to add another answer.

Comment: I'm glad you liked it; please feel free to adopt it if you see fit.  I'm not planning to post an answer myself.